# Date formate is wrong while adding events in json

Tags: json, spring

I am trying to display events in calendar for that i set the values to json
while setting the values in json date attribute was set as "Mar 1,2017" but i need to set the date like 2017-03-01 in json value.

Here i give my coding

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/calender_view_get_json" }, method = RequestMethod.GET,headers = "Accept=*/*", produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody String viewCalenderJson(Model model, HttpSession session ,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ParseException {
        if(request.getRequestedSessionId()!=null&&!request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()){
            return "";
        }
        else{

            User user=(User) session.getAttribute("loggedinuserOb");
            List<calendar> events=teacherService.getLessonPlanByTeacherId(user.getId());
            Gson gson = new Gson();
           String jsonEvents = gson.toJson(events);


            return jsonEvents;
        }
    }
```

**Database access:**

```
public List<calendar> getLessonPlanByTeacherId(int t_id){


        List<LessonPlan> lst=new ArrayList<LessonPlan>();
        List<calendar> cl_list=new ArrayList<calendar>();
        try {
        Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
        Query q=session.createSQLQuery("select * from sts_class_lesson_plan where teacher_id=(select id from sts_teachers where app_user_id="+t_id+") and month(created_on)=month(utc_date())");
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        List<Object[]> rows=q.list();
        for (Object[] row : rows) {
            calendar cl=new calendar();



            cl.setStart((Date)row[1]); //May be problem in this line

            cl.setTitle((String)row[8]);
            cl_list.add(cl);
        }

        session.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return cl_list;
    }
```

**service:**

```
public List<calendar> getLessonPlanByTeacherId(int t_id){
        //List<calendar> cal_list=new ArrayList<calendar>();

        List<calendar> cl_list=teacherDAO.getLessonPlanByTeacherId(t_id);
return cl_list;
    }
```

**In datebase class i was getting the database values and set that in to the Model class calendar**

current getting date format : Mar 1,2017
required date format :2017-03-01

can any one help me to get this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On way to achieve what you are looking for would be in your controller method viewCalenderJson to replace your Gson instance construction by the following:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").create();
```